# Are there algorithms and tools that can optimize black box functions with black box constraints?

Tags: optimization, algorithms

Suppose that we have an objective function  $f$ which have as parameters $x_1, x_2$.

$f$ is an objective function to be maximized for a given problem.Lets say:

$$f(x_1,x_2)=x_1+x_2+E(x_1,x_2)$$

where $E$ is a neural network model. Thus $E$ is not expressed as an explicit mathematical relation.

Let's also assume that the problem have one constraint:

$$G(x_1, x_2) < C$$

where $C$ is a constant and $G$ as for $E$ is modelled using  a neural network.

My question is the following:

1. Is it possible to optimize this problem  assuming that we do not know how $F$ and $G$ executes the results?
2. Are there any tools that can deal with sort of problems?

Comment: Just for the newcomers, [GPflowOpt](https://gpflowopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/constrained_bo.html) offers this functionality. Also refer to their publication [GPflowOpt: a bayesian optimization library using tensorflow](https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/GPflowOpt-%3A-a-bayesian-optimization-library-using-Knudde-Herten/0f31fc6eb7d1a4705ff48b4a108abbaf9e0052ed) in NIPS 2017.

Comment: You can check this one (it deals with black-box problems without constraints, but you can add some penalty associated with the black-box constraints to get good solutions for your problem) https://github.com/coin-or/rbfopt/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For black-box optimization, most state of the art approaches currently use some form of [surrogate modeling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_model), also known as model-based optimization. This is where the objective function is locally approximated via some parametric model (e.g. linear/quadratic [response surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Response_surface_methodology) or [Gaussian process regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriging)). This approach is "[derivative free optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivative-free_optimization)" (DFO) in the sense that only the *parametric model* derivatives are used, vs. finite differences of the black-box function. Note that the local models are typically fitted in a "large" neighborhood, compared to finite differences.

A good comparison of the current state of the art in unconstrained (and box-constrained) DFO methods is the recent paper

> Rios, L. M., & Sahinidis, N. V. (2013) [Derivative-free optimization: a review of algorithms and comparison of software implementations.](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=13996631775177561404) Journal of Global Optimization.

This study benchmarks various DFO methods for global and local optimization. (See my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235862/is-it-possible-to-train-a-neural-network-without-backpropagation) for further discussion, including limits on problem size.)

For *constrained* optimization there is less work, but several generalizations exist for the polynomial response-surface DFO methods, at least. These methods tend to be formulated as [sequential linear programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Successive_linear_programming) or [sequential quadratic programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_quadratic_programming) (SQP) algorithms$\mathbf{^*}$, depending on the degree of the polynomial approximation. Note that cubic or higher order polynomials are generally *not* used, due to [ill conditioning](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/234197/127790).

I have not used these programs, but some possible recommendations might be:

- **Linear Case:** The [COBYLA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COBYLA) algorithm by [M.J.D. Powell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_J._D._Powell).
- **Quadratic Case:** [CONDOR](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=14177799118933242209) (based on an unconstrained SQP algorithm by Powell)

I have used Powell's box-constrained SQP solver ([BOBYQA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BOBYQA)) with good results, and his software/algorithms are very reliable in my experience, as they were honed by years of practical industrial applications. Hence my recommendation. (His quadratic DFO variants also rank very well in the benchmark study cited above.)

---

$\mathbf{^*}$[Penalty methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penalty_method) are a viable alternative for many constrained optimization problems, as suggested in the answer by [Ami Tavory](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/241120/127790) (since deleted). If you go this route, I would *not* recommend using [Nelder-Mead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nelder%E2%80%93Mead_method). Many better alternatives exist, as outlined in the [Rios & Sahinidis](https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=13996631775177561404) study.

Answer (score 3):

For this task I would use population-based optimisation algorithm, where, at each iteration you create a population of possible points (also referred to as *candidates*). At the "creation" time you check each candidate whether they meet the constraint $G$ and then, once the whole population is built, you evaluate the whole population using your black-box objective $f$.

A good Global Optimisation algorithms that you could look at are [*Genetic Algorithm*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genetic_algorithm), [*Particle Swarm Optimisation*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_swarm_optimization) or [*Simulated Annealing*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simulated_annealing) (see my response [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/435426/230011)). Other methods would include [*Pattern search*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_search_(optimization)) or, if evaluating your $E$ is expensive, [*Surrogate Optimisation*](https://www.mathworks.com/help/gads/surrogate-optimization-algorithm.html).

Answer (score 1):

So as a practical suggestion, can I suggest that you start by faking the constraints with a soft to hard penalty function and then try running the humpday package, or some other bbopt comparison tool like IOHprofiler?

As another practical suggestion, can I ask how long your objective takes to compute? If it is pretty fast, there is no way GP solutions are going to be best.

To some extent this [leaderboard](https://microprediction.github.io/optimizer-elo-ratings/html_leaderboards/overall.html) might be indicative. What you may find is that if there is no time constraint then GP/surrogate methods will be hard to beat, however for your problem you might find something like dlib more useful, just because it is so fast and you can try out various hacks to get around your constraint issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Nomad solver https://www.gerad.ca/fr/software/nomad/
It's a solver for constrained black box optimization based on the Mesh Adaptive Direct Search (MADS).